# Parse iOS SDK 'nearGeoPoint' and 'notContainedIn' not working together

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm quite newbie with parse iOS sdk and facing a strange problem. I would like to query objects which near geopoint and not contained in the array of objectId.

Here's what happened.

1. This return correct objects which not contained in arrayOfObjectIds:

   ```
   [query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:arrayOfObjectIds];
   //[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:point];
   ```
2. This return correct objects which near the geopoint I've pass to.

   ```
   //[query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:arrayOfObjectIds];
   [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:point];
   ```
3. This cause the problem, when I tried them both, it return 0 objects.

   ```
   [query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:arrayOfObjectIds];
   [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:point];
   ```

I know that when you have 2 constrains it act as 'AND' operation. But even I tried with EXACTLY the same result set when run separately, it still the same results.

So If they are "AND", they should they return the same results ?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then, actually you want to perform filter based on GeoPoint along with condition of NotContainedIn array of Object Ids.

If your answer is YES then,
`whereKey: nearGeoPoint:` will never filter the data, as it performs sorting.In your case the result of first case will be sorted by the nearness of the location due to `whereKey: nearGeoPoint:` method. [See the Doc of Parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:nearGeoPoint:)